# Convert text (words) to integer

Tags: c++

So I was making guessing game to learn something (I'm a beginner) and at the start I faced the problem that I didn't know how to do rng or something like that so I came up with idea where I just ask user to give his name and something he hates and I need to make this input somehow change to number (any kind except binary).

So in short I need a way to change any inputted text (string) to any integer number.

Comment: Search term: Hashing.

Comment: Look up hashing.  It has been used for a long time to convert strings to numbers.

Comment: [`std::hash<std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) is already provided by the standard library.

Comment: wouldn't it have had made more sense to ask how to use rng? (or even better, google how to use rng)

Comment: This is an XY problem. You don't need to know how to hash things, but how to set a random seed.

Comment: "any kind except binary" - WAT? A binary number is the same as a decimal, octal, hexidecimal or *any other encoding* of a number. A number is a number; decimal, hex, binary, etc is just an encoding - how you write/represent it - it doesn't change the actual number in the slightest.

Comment: Why not just sum the ASCII values of each character in a word to produce a final number? Or you can use one of the existing string-hashing methods like *lh_strhash, murmur, qhash or djb2*? (or a simple numeric extraction from `md5sum` or the like?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use a hash function, that already exists for the standard library.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Starting Process!" << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Enter Name: ";
  std::string name;
  std::cin >> name;

  std::hash<std::string> hash_fn;
  size_t str_hash = hash_fn(name);

  std::cout << str_hash << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at the "random" library if you want rng or to use hashing as other suggested.

If you want to generate yourself pseudo-random numbers from an input string, you could do the following:

1. To acces a character, you could use the [ ] operator, something like that:

```
    std::string str = "The Name";
    str[index]; // to acces a character
```

2. Cast the characters into integers to work with them. Keep in mind that every character has an ASCII value, so you could do something like this:

```
    static_cast<int>(str[2]);
```

Now you have accesed the third character, according to the string above, 'e'. Which happens to be 101 when transformed into an int (remember, the ASCII value).

You can then create some algorithm using that.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the pseudo random number generator will always provide the same sequence of results. So if the user enters the same name and "something he hates" then they will end up getting exactly the same game every time.

Comment: @TimRandall Yeah, that's a downside. You have to either acces the time or hardware in some way to get a really random number. I considered that's a simple enough solution, easy to digest, he probably won't understand a hashing algorithm or how random library works anyway if he's a beginner, so transforming the characters in integers might be the easiest solution.

Comment: [Documentation for the Random library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: @TimRandall I know about that so I have prepared some stuff after "warm up" :)